# Can we convert .class file into .exe file

Tags: java, jsp, exe

**Is there any way to convert class file into exe file ?
Suppose i created a java desktop application and want to convert into exe **

Comment: please use google on how to convert java program to exe...

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible, but you can create a `.bat` file if you are using Windows with script like:

```
@echo off
java myProgram
```

Ultimately, the user still need to have JVM installed.